# How can you make transitions when changing screens?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Could you help me? I have the following code

```
.container__login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--blanco);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
```

But the transition doesn't work, in this case that's when you press next and this section is shown. Therefore I can't use pseudo-classes on this element, is there a way to create transitions only when I press the "Next" button and it appears smoothly.

Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi,maybe you can check the  component of vue.js.
   https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html
   this is an easy way.
2. And there is also another simple way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .container__login {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: blue;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transition: all 200ms ease-out;
        opacity: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="next">next</button>
    <div class="container__login" id="container"></div>
    <script>
      const next = document.getElementById("next");
      const container = document.getElementById("container");
      next.addEventListener("click", function () {
        container.style.opacity = 1;
      });

      console.log(container.style);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you set the original container style's opacticy as 0.And when the button is clicked,change the opacity into 1.

3. another way is to register a keyframe,and set the original display style of the container as 'none'.And when the button is clicked,set the containers dispaly attribute as 'flex',this just like the vue transition component.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .container__login {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: blue;
        display: none;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transition: all 200ms ease-out;
        /* opacity: 0; */
        animation: slide 4s ease;
      }
      @keyframes slide {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="next">next</button>
    <div class="container__login" id="container"></div>
    <script>
      const next = document.getElementById("next");
      const container = document.getElementById("container");
      next.addEventListener("click", function () {
        container.style.display = "flex";
      });

      console.log(container.style);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not good at writign in english,fogive me.

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry. The important is that i understood. Again thanks so much

Comment: Thanks. the second way worked perfect. Also, you can use within my code.